# HTTP リクエストボディをファイル保存するだけのサーバー

Tags: windows, http

ブラウジングしながら特定のサイト内のサーバーレスポンスを
ローカルPCファイルに保存し続けたいです

---

これまでにも何度か質問させていただいてchrome-extension で javascript 上にレスポンスを文字列として取得するまではできました

ただここから直接ファイルに保存するのが javascript のセキュリティ的に無理そうなので、ローカルに保存する為だけのサーバーをたてようかと思っています

Windows 上で http リクエストを受け取ってリクエストボディを保存するサーバーを手軽に実現できる方法はないでしょうか
ウェブサーバーだと apache とか nginx とかしか使ったことがなくてその上に CGI をのせてその中でリクエストボディをファイル保存するみたいなことをすればできそうではあるんですが

ruby, python, java, node あたりははいってるのでワンライナーとかリダイレクトあたりで手軽に実現できないでしょうか

リクエストボディのみでヘッダ情報は一切不要
完全に自分用で公開したり配布したりしないのでセキュリティとかもどうでもよくて最低限落ちてる(起動忘れてる)のに気付けるとうれしいです

よろしくおねがいします

---

これまでの関連質問

[ブラウザで開いてるページの ajax 通信の内容を自動でローカルファイルに残したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/76026/%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e3%81%a7%e9%96%8b%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%83%9a%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%ae-ajax-%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%ae%e5%86%85%e5%ae%b9%e3%82%92%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e3%81%a7%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ab%e3%83%ab%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ab%e6%ae%8b%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)
[chrome extension 内からローカルファイルに書き込むことってできませんか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/78113/chrome-extension-%e5%86%85%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%82%ab%e3%83%ab%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%ab%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e8%be%bc%e3%82%80%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubyのワンライナーだとたとえばこうです。

```
ruby -r webrick -e 'f = open("body.txt", "ab"); s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(Port: 4000); s.mount_proc("/"){|req,res| f.puts(req.body); res.status = 200; res.body = "ok\n"}; s.start'
```

この例はカレントディレクトリの body.txt というファイルに追加保存していきます。

なお、最新のRubyだと webrick は事前に `gem install webrick` でインストールする必要があります。

Comment: うまくいきました！　powershell で直接打ち込んだところなぜか -e:1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')' となったんですが ruby ファイルにかいて ruby log_server.rb で実行したら書き込みできました！

Comment: PowerShell の場合はクオートを `"` にする必要があります。そうするとスクリプト内の `"` とぶつかるのでスクリプト内は `'` にするのが単純です。さらにレスポンスボディの末尾に `"\n"` を指定していますが、このエスケープは `'` では無効なので `\n` を削除するかレスポンスボディを `%!ok\n!` のように書くことで回避します。

`ruby -r webrick -e "f = open('body.txt', 'ab'); s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(Port: 4000); s.mount_proc('/'){|req,res| f.puts(req.body); res.status = 200; res.body = %!ok\n!}; s.start"`

Answer (score 0):

目的とあっているかわかりませんが、電子ペーパーの通信解析(未完)用にずっと前に作成したツールを参考実装として紹介しておきます。

https://github.com/raccy/denshi_paper/tree/master/tool

これはリバースプロキシとして動作し、アクセスすると指定のIPアドレス宛にそのままリクエストを投げてそのレスポンスをそのまま返します。Vagrant上で実行して、hostsあたりを書き替えれば、特定サイトだけそのままアクセスできると思います。全てのリクエストとレスポンスを標準出力に表示するようにしていますが、適当なファイルにリダイレクトするか、その部分を書き替えればいいでしょう。

中身を見ればわかりますが、実装は本当にリクエストとレスポンスの受け渡しなので割と単純です。ただ、Cookie周りは工夫しないとうまくいかなったので、色々しています(なぜ、こうなっているのかは記憶に無いので、詳しいことは聞かないでください)。特定のメソッドだけで、Cookieとかを考慮しないとかでないと、ワンライナーで実現するのは難しいと思います。

ただ、電子ペーパー専用に作り込んでいる(mDNS通知とか、8080ポートを使うとか)ので、実装は参考程度にして、書き替えるか、作り直してください。(ライセンスは一つ上のディレクトリにあるLICENSEにMITと書いてあるので、煮るなり焼くなりご自由に)

なお、普通に解析目的なら[Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic)等を使った方が簡単だと思われます。

Comment: すみません　README読んでみたんですが最初に頂いた回答のほうが簡単だしカスタマイズもしやすそうだったのでワンラーナの方を使わせていただきました。　あと Fiddler Classic　は別の質問でも教えていただいたんですが content_type のフィルタに text/plain がなくて画像とかを取り除く方法がよくわからなかったので諦めてしまいました